# BrowserHistory is not working when user is on the same base url with different Query parmas

Tags: reactjs, react-router

BrowserHistory is not working when i am on the same base URL but with different query parameters.

```
// currently i am on same url but different query param's.

**settings/organization/appointment-manager?from=2020-04-04T09:58:29.761Z&to=2020-04-04T09:58:29.761Z&pageNo=1&pageSize=30&activeKey=3**


import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';


refresh(){

// I want to call componentDidMount again when i push the bellow URL.

const startDate = moment();
const endDate = moment();
 browserHistory.push(`/settings/organization/appointment-manager?from=${startDate}&to=${endDate}&pageNo=1&pageSize=30&activeKey=3`);
}
```

When refresh() called my URL changed with new parameter but componentDidMount() is not called.

How componentDidMount() can be called again when i am on the same Base URL with different query param's.

Comment: Use componentDidUpdate if you want to call something in update phase. componentDidMount is only called while mounting the component.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do here is you should use `componentWillRecieveProps()`. Because all you are doing is that you are updating `router` props.

So try doing this one:

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.location.search !== this.props.location.search) {
            //search params have changed
        }
    }
```

or for newer version of React

```
    getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.location.search !== this.props.location.search) {
            //search params have changed
        }
    }
```

Comment: componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated